# Equivalent of Eagle's "Design Blocks" in KiCAD

Tags: eaglecad, kicad

Is there an equivalent in KiCAD for "design block" concept in Eagle? If not, what is the most sensible way to accomplish this in KiCAD?

**This is not a "how to import" question.** I have started a new design in KiCAD and have a subcircuit that is repeated identically both in schematic and in pcb layout 12 times. I have recently learned about hierarchical sheets, however, this helps me only on the schematic side. Is there a way to duplicate the layout identically multiple times?

I am not even sure how I would copy-paste without breaking the schematic-pcb relation. I guess there is a "duplicate" tool in pcb editor, however this leaves annotations identically and therefore makes every node in the subcircuit to connect corresponding node in every other copy. Also it doesn't transfer to schematic.

*For those unfamiliar with Eagle's design blocks, design blocks consisted of a standalone schematic and pcb layout. In the main schematic, you would add this like a normal part, it would copy the schematic and layout exactly. You could add these many times, or to irrelevant projects.*

Comment: This seems to be the currently preferred way to duplicate a layout: https://github.com/MitjaNemec/ReplicateLayout.  It requires hierarchical sheets.  There is a video that works through a simple example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJXADScAhN0.

Comment: I believe there's a feature request for this on the KiCad gitlab. Maybe go find that and upvote it so the devs know that people want this feature.